# VB.NET array = array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to create a program in which I'm assigning array to array. They are declared like that:

Const Deck_Size = 52

Private Deck(Deck_Size), Table_Deck(Deck_Size) As String

So, in my program I have written this line:

**Deck = Table_Deck**

And what this does, how i can understand from results I'm getting, that "Table_Deck" pointer have been assign to "Deck". For e.g.

Table_Deck = "As","Ks","Qs","Js",...

Deck = "2h", "3h", "4h", "5h",...

After this code line: Deck = Table_Deck, I have this:

Table_Deck = "As","Ks","Qs","Js",...

Deck = "As","Ks","Qs","Js",...

And here comes the problem.

When the next code line is done (which is: **Table_Deck(1) = Table_Deck(4)**), I get this result: **Table_Deck = "Js","Ks","Qs","Js",...**, but as well "Deck" changes too...

**Deck = "Js","Ks","Qs","Js",...**

So, I assume that this is pointers fault. Can anyone tell me how I can solve this problem, if I want to change element in only one array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, your assignment changes the array reference.  Afterwards, both Deck and Table_Deck reference the exact same array.  So any changes you make to Deck's content will be visible through the Table_Deck reference as well.  You have to copy the content instead:

```
    Table_Deck.CopyTo(Deck, 0)
```